# Strange problem with resources - not seeing fields

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have resource file in my project, which contains translations. In my Resource folder I have Resource.en.resx and (default) Resource.resx.

Everything is working fine, except one thing:

It shows error only on one of my properties, which is defined in resources in exactly same way as the other:

[image]

Anyone had encountered that? And how to fix it? It looks like VS bug.

Comment: Right-click your `Resources.resx` and `Run Custom Tool`. Does that help? If it does, then I suspect either you hand-edited the resx and didn't re-run the C# code generation step (it's run when you use the editor in your right-hand screenshot, but not if you edit the file directly), or the relationship between the Resx and the tool got messed up in your csproj.

Comment: Wait, `Languages.Resource` isn't the default name for the generated C# class, it's normally `Resources`. Can you "Go To Definition" on `Languages.Resource` and just double-check what's there?

Comment: @canton7 It's just the reference and it works for other strings :)

Comment: I just wanted to check that it has the structure of a file created by `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`, and not some other tool, since it has the wrong name. If you want an answer, it's generally a good idea to respond positively to questions from the people trying to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other projects which are referncing project with those resources it's necessary to remove refernce and re-add it.

The problem is rare and occures irregularly.

Another solution is to build project with resources. After building, errors are gone.